# ZF2 new module breaks routing

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm having an odd problem. If I have 1 module my routes are correctly matched and the pages returned. Add another module to the application config and BANG - it stops working and ends up in the Module.php of my second module (which has boostrapping and triggers loads of events).

application.config.php

```
<?php
return array(
    'modules' => array(        
        'CMS',
        'AOCS',
    ),
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'config_glob_paths'    => array(
            'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        ),
        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ),
    ),
);
```

CMS module config

```
<?php
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(                   
            'Admin' => array(        
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/admin',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'CMS\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'Login',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
            ),
            'Logout' => array(        
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/logout',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'CMS\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'Logout',
                    ),
                ),
            ),                                    
            'CMS/Welcome' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/aocs/welcome',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'AOCS\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Welcome',
                        'action'        => 'Welcome',
                    ),
                ),                
            ),                      
        ),
    ),   
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'CMS\Controller\Index' => 'CMS\Controller\IndexController',
        ),
    ),
    'translator' => array(
        'locale' => 'en_GB',        
    ),    
    'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../templates/admin.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',          
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),      
    ),
);
```

AOCS module config

```
<?php
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(                                         
            'Welcome' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/welcome',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'AOCS\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Welcome',
                        'action'        => 'Welcome',
                    ),
                ),                
            ),            
            'Mains' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/aocs[/:controller][/:action][/:id]',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'AOCS\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Welcome',
                        'action'        => 'Welcome',
                    ),                   
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes'  => array(
                    'query' => array(
                        'type' => 'Query',
                    ),
                ),                                               
            ),            

        ),
    ),
    'navigation' => array(
        'menu' => array(
            'page-1' => array(
                'label' => 'Logout',
                'route' => 'Logout',
                'resource' => 'aocs_index_logout'
            ),
            'page-2' => array(
                'label' => 'Login',
                'route' => 'Admin' ,
                'resource' => 'cms_index_login'
            ),
        ),
    ),    
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
          'menu' => 'AOCS\Navigation\MenuNavigationFactory'
        ),
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'AOCS\Controller\Welcome' => 'AOCS\Controller\WelcomeController'
        ),
    ),
    'translator' => array(
        'locale' => 'en_GB',        
    ),    
    'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../templates/admin.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',          
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
        /*'strategies' => array(
            'ViewJsonStrategy',
        ),*/        
    ),
);
```

Module.php from CMS

```
<?php
/**
 * Zend Framework (http://framework.zend.com/)
 *
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2012 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

namespace CMS;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;   
use Zend\View\Renderer\JsonRenderer;
use Zend\Di\Di;        
use Zend\Config\Reader\Ini;
use Zend\Navigation\Navigation;

// AH core code
use Core\Classes\setDB;
use Core\Classes\setCache;
use Core\Models\SecurityModel;
use Core\Models\AclModel;

class Module
{   
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();

        $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);       

        // Set config - required throughout
        $reader = new Ini;
        $sm->setService('configIni',$reader->fromFile('./config/application.ini'));        

        // Setup a Database connection
        $sm->setService('setDB',new setDB($sm,'database')); 

        // Setup Caching
        $sm->setService('setCache',new setCache($sm));

        /*$eventManager->attach('dispatch', function ($sm) use ($controllers) {
          print'<pre>[CMS]';print_r($sm->getRouteMatch());print'</pre>';
          exit;         
        }, 100); // execute before executing action logic*/         

        // Assign system names to view models so we can set across templates
        $view = $e->getViewModel();
        $config = $sm->get('configIni');
        $view->setVariable('systemname',$config['system']['name']);
        $view->setVariable('systemshort',$config['system']['shortname']);                             
    }    

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Am I missing something obvious? Its really annoying!

Thanks

Antony

Comment: Can you give us more concrete information about the BANG:). What do you get as an exception or error.

Comment: Meanwhile, two things to consider. (1) You cannot use slash `/`  in a route name. This slash is used to navigate to child routes. (2) The latest version of ZF2 deprecated the Query route(r) so you cannot use `'query' => array('type' => 'Query')` anymore (Module AOCS still has it).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!

The BANG was that I have a dispatch in the 2x Modules.php which for some reason were triggering automatically. As the 2nd checked if the user is logged in and they weren't it redirected causing problems.

The issue wasn't to do with my config it appears (unless I'm missing the obvious) that this is a bug in ZF2 where the dispatch events are not tied to the module they're called from but all get run automatically.

So if my page is in CMS module the AOCS modules > bootstrap is still run. Why??

Thanks for the point about type = Query - will update.

Comment: The ModuleManager loads every module, and calls onBootstrap() for every module that supplies one regardless of if it's the module that will be ultimately dispatched, but that's not the problem here. If you only want your listener to listen to its own controllers dispatch event see Evan Coury's blog post on module specific layouts. http://blog.evan.pro/module-specific-layouts-in-zend-framework-2 The principle is the same, listening to the dispatch event when triggered by a specific modules` controller(s)